# Чтение чисел из stdin в массив

Tags: rust

Допустим у нас есть массив структур,где экземпляр структуры описывает человека. Поля структуры  - имя и возраст.
Чтобы не читать данные этих полей из stdin в строку, так как это опснода и не хочется  парсить потом строку в поисках чисел, читать я всё это буду в массивы u8.
И тут возникает проблема - функция read читает из stdin код числа, а не само число.
Можно ли это как-то изменить или преобразовать код числа в число?

```rust
use std::io::{self, Write, Read};
use std::str;
 
static AMOUNT: usize = 3;
 
//создаём структуру
struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: u8
}
 
 
fn main() {
 
    let mut people: Vec<Person> = Vec::with_capacity(AMOUNT); //вектор структур 
    let mut raw_name: [u8; 30] = [0; 30]; // буффер, куда мы будем читать имя из потока
    let mut age:  [u8; 2]  = [0; 2]; //буффер, куда мы будем читать возраст из потока
    let mut name: String = String::new();   //2-ой байт, чтобы ловить символ новой строки
    
    for _ in 0..AMOUNT {
        
        print!("Имя: ");
        io::stdout().flush().unwrap(); 
        io::stdin().read(&mut raw_name).unwrap();
        
        print!("Возраст: ");
        io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
        io::stdin().read(&mut age).unwrap();
        
        name = str::from_utf8(&mut raw_name)
            .unwrap()
            .trim_matches(|c| c == ' ' || c == '\n')
            .to_string();
        
        let tmp: Person = Person {name: name.clone(), age: age[0]};
        
        people.push(tmp);
        name.clear();
    }
 
     
    for index in 0..AMOUNT {
        
        println!("{}", people[index].name);
        println!("{}", people[index].age);
        
    }
}
```

Будет выводить код числа

```rust
println!("{}", people[index].age);
```

Можно в этом легко убедиться: так выводит нужное нам число.

```rust
println!("{}", people[index].age as char);
```

и еще trim_matches почему-то не удаляет символ новой строки

Answer (score 1):

> Можно ли это как-то изменить или преобразовать код числа в число?

Да, нужно из каждой цифры отнять код числа 0.

```
age: age[0] - b'0'
```

> и еще trim_matches почему-то не удаляет символ новой строки

Вы вызываете функцию `str::from_utf8` для всего буфера `[u8; 30]`. Внутри эта функция проверяет только корректность последовательности для `utf8`, а потом возвращает ссылку на этот же кусок памяти в виде строки.

Это означает, что при вводе имени `Ваня` в функцию передаётся массив содержащий `Ваня\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0` и trim просто не срабатывает на такой строке.

Для корректной обработки вы можете получить от функции `read` количество считанных байт и передать только нужный кусок.

```
let name_len = io::stdin().read(&mut raw_name).unwrap();
name = str::from_utf8(&raw_name[0..name_len]).unwrap().trim().to_string();
```

Ещё для избежания проблем с синхронизацией я рекомендую запросить `stdin` и `stdout` до цикла. А для лучшей обработки ошибок в main можно возвращать `Result<(), io::Error>`

```
fn main() -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    let mut people: Vec<Person> = Vec::with_capacity(AMOUNT); //вектор структур
    let mut raw_name: [u8; 30] = [0; 30]; // буффер, куда мы будем читать имя из потока
    let mut age: [u8; 2] = [0; 2]; //буффер, куда мы будем читать возраст из потока
    let mut name: String = String::new(); //2-ой байт, чтобы ловить символ новой строки

    let mut stdout = io::stdout();
    let mut stdin = io::stdin();

    for _ in 0..AMOUNT {
        print!("Имя: ");
        stdout.flush()?;
        let name_len = stdin.read(&mut raw_name)?;

        print!("Возраст: ");
        stdout.flush()?;
        stdin.read(&mut age)?;

        name = str::from_utf8(&raw_name[0..name_len]).unwrap().trim().to_string();

        let tmp: Person = Person {
            name: name.clone(),
            age: age[0] - b'0',
        };

        people.push(tmp);
        name.clear();
    }

    for index in 0..AMOUNT {
        println!("{}", people[index].name);
        println!("{}", people[index].age);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Но в целом я не вижу особого смысла в том чтобы использовать `u8` буферы в данному случае. Это только всё усложняет, да и возраст у вас даже двузначный не запишется.

```
use std::io::{self, Write};

const AMOUNT: usize = 3;

//создаём структуру
#[derive(Default)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: u8,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    let mut people: Vec<Person> = Vec::with_capacity(AMOUNT); //вектор структур
    let mut buf = String::new();

    let mut stdout = io::stdout();
    let stdin = io::stdin();

    for _ in 0..AMOUNT {
        let mut person = Person::default();

        print!("Имя: ");
        stdout.flush()?;
        stdin.read_line(&mut buf)?;
        person.name = buf.trim().to_owned();
        buf.clear();

        print!("Возраст: ");
        stdout.flush()?;
        stdin.read_line(&mut buf)?;
        person.age = buf.trim().parse().unwrap_or_default();
        buf.clear();

        people.push(person);
    }

    for p in &people {
        println!("{} {}", p.name, p.age);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Хоть убейте, но не хочу использовать чтение в строку из-за небезопасности этого метода. А какие проблемы с синхронизацией могут быть?

Comment: Не знаю как у вас, но у меня под Arch на втором проходе цикла строки "Имя" и "Возраст" выводятся одновременно. Я редко делаю пользовательский ввод, так что не могу сказать причину такого поведения.
А какие проблемы с безопасностью вы видите? Мне кажется мой метод безопаснее хотя бы тем, что возраст не считается из буквы.

Comment: Я использую Debian и у мня всё нормально с чтением. Если две строки печатаются вряд, то, скорее всего, символ новой строки остаётся во входном потоке.
Опасность в том, что функции вроде read_line читают данные в вектор пока не встретят терминирующи  символ - символ новой строки. Но такое символа в потоке можети не оказаться.

Comment: На мой взгляд проблема высосана из пальца. В более реальных задачах вы не будете просить ввести такой список в терминале. Скорее всего вы получите его запросом из базы или прочитав из файла. Так что не вижу смысла заморачиваться.